# maven compilation error that I don't understand

Tags: maven

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) on project fai-service: Compilation failure: Compilation failure: 
[ERROR] /C:/Users/java/Documents/ridcom_fe/fai-service-be/src/test/java/it/fai/riduzioni_compensate/test/base/ConfigurationTest.java:[24,36] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   method getLegaleSempliceSftpPassword()
[ERROR]   location: variable configurationUtil of type it.fai.riduzioni_compensate.configuration.LegaleSempliceConfigurationUtil
[ERROR] /C:/Users/java/Documents/ridcom_fe/fai-service-be/src/test/java/it/fai/riduzioni_compensate/test/base/ConfigurationTest.java:[25,36] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   method getLegaleSempliceSftpAttivo()
[ERROR]   location: variable configurationUtil of type it.fai.riduzioni_compensate.configuration.LegaleSempliceConfigurationUtil
[ERROR] /C:/Users/java/Documents/ridcom_fe/fai-service-be/src/test/java/it/fai/riduzioni_compensate/test/base/ConfigurationTest.java:[26,36] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   method getLegaleSempliceSftpReaderFolder()
[ERROR]   location: variable configurationUtil of type it.fai.riduzioni_compensate.configuration.LegaleSempliceConfigurationUtil
[ERROR] /C:/Users/java/Documents/ridcom_fe/fai-service-be/src/test/java/it/fai/riduzioni_compensate/test/base/ConfigurationTest.java:[27,36] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   method getLegaleSempliceSftpSenderFolder()
[ERROR]   location: variable configurationUtil of type it.fai.riduzioni_compensate.configuration.LegaleSempliceConfigurationUtil
[ERROR] /C:/Users/java/Documents/ridcom_fe/fai-service-be/src/test/java/it/fai/riduzioni_compensate/test/base/ConfigurationTest.java:[28,36] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   method getLegaleSempliceSftpServer()
[ERROR]   location: variable configurationUtil of type it.fai.riduzioni_compensate.configuration.LegaleSempliceConfigurationUtil
[ERROR] /C:/Users/java/Documents/ridcom_fe/fai-service-be/src/test/java/it/fai/riduzioni_compensate/test/base/ConfigurationTest.java:[29,36] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   method getLegaleSempliceSftpUserName()
[ERROR]   location: variable configurationUtil of type it.fai.riduzioni_compensate.configuration.LegaleSempliceConfigurationUtil
```

Comment: project uploaded in spring tool suite, git

Answer (score 0):

Your tests have compile errors, probably missing dependencies.